# Rails - making a route for ajax search in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an class called contribution which belongs_to users. /contributions/new.html.erb I includes the following code to search for a user for a new contribution to belong to.

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search" %>
<%= link_to "Search", contributions_path, id: "search_submit" %>
```

- the path is wrong.

In routes.rb I have

```
resources :contributions do
   get :search, on: :collection
end
```

and rake routes includes

```
search_contributions GET    /contributions/search(.:format)   contributions#search
```

In application.js.erb I have -

```
$(document).on("click", "a#search_submit", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      data: {query: $("#search").val() },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
      }
   });
});
```

What is the proper path to have in the view to call the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contributions_path` points to `index` of `contributions_controller.rb`, however, you need to point it to `search` of `contributions_controller.rb`

You need to update your `link_to` from:

```
<%= link_to "Search", contributions_path, id: "search_submit" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Search", search_contributions_path, id: "search_submit" %>
```

Now it will point to `contributions#search` instead of `contributions#index`.

Comment: Hi Raj - I get Unknown action
The action 'search' could not be found for ContributionsController - I should create a search  action and include the code for searching for a user? This is a new area for me.

Comment: Yes you are right. You need to define `search` action in your `contributions` controller.

Comment: When I add the search action, the controller is trying to call a page called search - I want to trigger the ajax routine defined in application.js.erb above within the original contributions/new.html.erb form. (thanks for your help btw)

Comment: @RADan, Glad that it helped you for asked problem. Furthermore, you should add another question for further issues, so that other users also can take advantage. Anyways, you need to `render` json form your action.. http://expected.co/eriknomitch/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-json--rails

Answer (score 0):

`rake routes` shows proper name for you:

```
search_contributions GET    /contributions/search(.:format)   contributions#search
```

so, should be `search_contributions_path`